# Ionic 3 sync mobile application with webserver data even if app is not running

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

We have a ionic 3 application which is creating a native calendar event in google calendar / IOS native calendar. The data for these calendar events is provided by the webserver (REST API)

We want to sync the calendar events, even if application is not running for few days?
We would like to keep the application in sync with the data that is present on the webserver.

Steps

1. User opens the app , Rest API is called and with data received
   calendar events are created
2. User kills the application
3. And data on web server is updated
4. How do we sync/update data changed on web
   server even if user does not open the application ?

Comment: If I understood correctly, Try using websocket so that your server can always push changes to your app.

Comment: @RxJS I believe web socket connection will work only when app is running. How about when app is not running (i.e. when app is killed) ?

Comment: Then you have to build some push mechanism from backend. Depends what kind of backend is yours.